# .bash_profile syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: macos, unix, macos-sierra, bash

OS: macOS Sierra v10.12.2

I was trying to get R working from the command line and ran into this problem, probably because I am relatively new to coding and messed with something I should not have.

Upon opening new terminal:

```
-bash: /Users/Brad/.bash_profile: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

When I inspect the profile it looks like this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"

eval "$(hub alias -s)"

  prompt_ruby_info() {
    if [ -f ".ruby-version" ]; then
      cat .ruby-version
    fi
  }

GREEN=$(tput setaf 65)

ORANGE=$(tput setaf 166)

NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)

precmd () { PS1="${ORANGE}[%~] ${GREEN}$(prompt_ruby_info) ${NORMAL}$ " }

export CLICOLOR=1;

export LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad;
```

Any information on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated; I don't want to keep messing around and making it worse!

Thank You!

Comment: Posting your code at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) will reveal syntax errors. Adding `;` just before the closing `}` of the `precmd` function should fix your issue. If the closing `}` is _on the same line_ as a command, the command must always be `;`-terminated.

Answer (score 7):

This line :

```
precmd () { PS1="${ORANGE}[%~] ${GREEN}$(prompt_ruby_info) ${NORMAL}$ " }
```

Misses a semi-colon at the end :

```
precmd () { PS1="${ORANGE}[%~] ${GREEN}$(prompt_ruby_info) ${NORMAL}$ " ; }
```

From the Bash reference manual :

> { list; }
>
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes
>   the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is
>   created. The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

This means you could also write :

```
precmd ()
{
  PS1="${ORANGE}[%~] ${GREEN}$(prompt_ruby_info) ${NORMAL}$ "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missed semicolon (;) at line number 27:

```
precmd () { PS1="${ORANGE}[%~] ${GREEN}$(prompt_ruby_info) ${NORMAL}$ "; }
```